# FFmpeg: How to make video with silent sound from single image

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I need to make a flv video from single picture with silent aac sound.
Video params I needed:

- fps - 30
- duration - 60 secs
- audio rate 44100
- size 1920×108
- pix_fmt yuv420p

Here is the sample command, but it doesn't work:

> `ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 60 -i img.jpg -t 60 -ar 44100 -ac 2
>   -f s16le  -i /dev/zero -c:v libx264 -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y
>   -strict experimental out.flv`

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It might help if you told us what happens when you run that command.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not helpful. Please include the **complete** ffmpeg console output to show any actual errors.

Comment: I don't see `-c:a aac`. Shouldn't you put that in for `aac`?